# Bug with next-i18next and deployment on vercel (recently)

Tags: aws-lambda, next.js, serverless, vercel, next-i18next

#### Update 2:

This probably has to do with the this [PR](https://github.com/vercel/nft/pull/304) where assets have been removed as dependency.

#### Update 1:

Managed to get a reverse shell into the serverless function and it really would appear that there is no `public` folder anymore:

[image]

[image]

#### Provide environment information

```
"next": "12.2.5", // Also tested on 12.2.6-canary.7 and 12.1.6
"next-i18next": "12.0.0", // Also tested on 10.5.0
"react": "18.2.0", // Also tested on 17.0.2
"react-dom": "18.2.0" // Also tested on 17.0.2
```

#### How are you deploying your application?

Vercel

#### Bug Description

##### Context

We encountered a bug around next-i18next that resulted in serverless crashes for catch-all routes. We noticed this bug for the first time Monday around 14:00 CET and think it is potentially related with a change in the serverless runtime/filestructure as older deployments that used to work stoped working when redeploying.

Some other people also seemed to have encountered the same bug. See also here:

- [This discod thread](https://discord.com/channels/752553802359505017/1013900674871873627)
- [This next-i18next bug report](https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/1935)
- [Stackoverflow same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73539195/you-will-need-to-pass-in-an-i18next-instance-by-using-initreacti18next-vercel-de)

##### What we tried

So we upgraded our versions of next and next-i18next (like some of the other people did).
With the most recent next.js and next-i18next versions translations seem to work only in very specific cases.

We created a minimal replicable deployment ([Repo](https://github.com/everdropde/ed-i18n-bug)) where we prebuild two pages via putting them in `getStaticPaths`:

- https://ed-i18n-bug.vercel.app/en/test/prebuild
- https://ed-i18n-bug.vercel.app/de/test/prebuild

Both pages do not use translations when opening them directly.

However, when first navigating to the [index.js](https://ed-i18n-bug.vercel.app/) and then clicking on of the links the two pages use proper translation.

**Note:** The translations will break upon refresh.

#### Setup Description

- catch all route in pages folder
- page set to static site generation
- default locale is set
- incremental static regeneration is on

#### Expected Behavior

working Translations

#### Links to Reproduce

Example repo here: https://github.com/everdropde/ed-i18n-bug
Example Vercel Deployment: https://ed-i18n-bug.vercel.app/de

#### Steps To Reproduce

1. Clone the Repo and deploy it to Vercel
2. Click any link on page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/40130

Setting env variable `VERCEL_CLI_VERSION=vercel@28.1.4` fix the issue

Also if you set `outputFileTracing: true` in `next.config.js` it works with latest CLI version

Comment: How do I set the env variable when we are auto-deploying on merge? I'm setting `outputFileTracing: true`, but still can't get this to work. Can you elaborate a bit? I'm using the latest version of both `next-i18next` and `next`.

Comment: Never mind, I was missing `localePath`, which is missing in docs. It's nice to add as I think many Next.js projects are deployed on Vercel.

Answer (score 3):

if you have `outputFileTracing` enabled and using latest version of Next.js then this should work with latest CLI version